# Unable to install Windows 10 Sdk Tools

Tags: sdk, windows-10

I have Windows 10 build 10532 with Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. Since VS 2015 RTM does not come with Windows 10 tools, I wanted to download and install it. When I run the intallation file Visual Studio block set up and gives an error

> Invalid entries passed to /Filterfeatureselectiontree swich.

What should I do?

Comment: VS 2015 rtm DOES come with Windows 10 SDK and tools.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows SDK receives updates separately from Visual Studio releases, so you may have to reinstall/update the Windows SDK.

You can trigger the latest install from within Visual Studio.

1. First, make sure you have the latest Visual Studio 2015 from http://aka.ms/vs2015ce
2. From the File menu, click File|New|Project
3. In the "New Project" dialog box, choose the Universal item on the left panel under Templates/Visual C#/Windows/Universal
4. On the right panel, note that you will either have some Win10 templates or a single item that suggests that you need to download the Win10 SDK. (You may see both templates and the download suggestion if have an older version of the SDK and there is a newer version available)
5. Click on the item to download the new Win10 SDK and click OK.
6. This should kick off the download/install process and you may be prompted to close Visual Studio as soon the installer is running.
7. When it's all done, go back to File|New|Project and try to create a blank app project.

[image]

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for reply but nothing worked for me and I had to reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: @Omer, After reinstalling Visual Studio, were you able to create a new Blank App project and run it?

Comment: Yes I were able to do it.